# mySQL on Docker connection auto disconnected

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a mySQL db running on a docker container and flask/python running on another docker container. I am connecting to the db using mysql.connector.connect.

All queries work perfectly. However, after a few hours (by observing the time elapsed, I believe 7-8 hours), the mySQL container automatically disconnects the connection.

How do I reconnect the connection? Or is there a way to change the settings such that the connection is not automatically disconnected?

I have tried `cnx.close()` and `cnx.reconnect()`. However, both these calls do not return and the the program does not execute further.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of a MySQL default setting : [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) 
After 28800 seconds (8 hours) of inactivity, the server closes the connection.

##### Option 1 : increase the timeout to meet your needs

In the MySQL container, set a new value via the `my.cnf` file

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout = xxxxx
```

##### Option 2 : use a connection pool

In your program, use [connection pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html). It will handle disconnections for you.

##### Pros and cons

|  | Advantage | Disadvantage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Option 1** | No further coding | Might block the MySQL server over time (1) |
| **Option 2** | Better usage of server's resources | Requires an effort to change the program |

(1) : depending on the concurrency in your program, keeping connections open could cause the server to reach the [maximum number of simultaneous connections allowed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections).